# работа с usb на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

я захотел написать программу, которая при обнаружении нового подключенного устройства (флешки, при чем, хочу заметить, что флешка может быть любая!) сканировала файлы с носителя, но я понятия не имею, каким образом это сделать

Comment: Искренне вам сочувствую! спасибо, что поделились!

Comment: И зачем таким как вы дали stackoverflow? Чтобы не помогать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускай `Gio.VolumeMonitor` на сигнал `mount-added`. В колбэк получил `Gio.Mount`, а с него `get_root` и `glob.glob(path+'/**/*')` получил список файлов для сканирования.

В Виндовс Gio получить можно через pygi-aio пакет, но не уверен что в виндовом Гноме эти интерфейсы работают.

Без библиотек это делается просмотром списка дисков в цикле.

```
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
```

или

```
open('/proc/mounts').readlines()
```